# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException exception in android while calling webservice?

Tags: java, android

I calling my webservice and make a dynamic code using call back .Initially i am sending **response string** but along with I am using gjson library which will not work for me .Now I am sending **Inputstream** on callback but get exception this..

```
   10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:161)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:159)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:244)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1298)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextQuotedValue(JsonReader.java:1028)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:796)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:178)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:183)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:805)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:743)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.firstgroup.applicationload.Appliacationload.getWebserviceResponse(Appliacationload.java:48)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.firstgroup.webservice.RequestTask.onPostExecute(RequestTask.java:77)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.firstgroup.webservice.RequestTask.onPostExecute(RequestTask.java:1)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**RequestTask class**

```
public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, InputStream>{
        private  WebserviceCallBack callBack;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressDialog= new ProgressDialog((Context) callBack);
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Webservice Call...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... uri) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            String responseString = null;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                    /*Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Holder response1 = gson.fromJson(reader, Holder.class);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    responseString = out.toString();*/
                    return response.getEntity().getContent();
                } else{
                    //Closes the connection.
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                //TODO Handle problems..\
                progressDialog.hide();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //TODO Handle problems..
                progressDialog.hide();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //Do anything with response..

            if(callBack!=null){
                callBack.getWebserviceResponse(result);
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog=null;

        }
        public void setObserver(WebserviceCallBack callback){
            callBack=callback;
        }


    }


and **call back** like that 


    public interface WebserviceCallBack {
        public void getWebserviceResponse(InputStream result);

    }

and **main activity** like that

    public class Appliacationload extends Activity implements WebserviceCallBack{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.appliacationload);

            /*WebserviceMethod callDepartudeDashboard=new WebserviceMethod();
            callDepartudeDashboard.setObserver(this);
            callDepartudeDashboard.getwebService(ConstantVariable.dashboardWebServiceURL+"a/"+"arrival"+"?crsCode=hnh");*/
            RequestTask callWebService=new RequestTask();
              callWebService.setObserver(this);
             callWebService.execute(ConstantVariable.dashboardWebServiceURL+"a/"+"arrival"+"?crsCode=vic");



        }

        @Override
        public void getWebserviceResponse(InputStream result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(result);
          Gson gson = new Gson();
        Holder response1 = gson.fromJson(reader, Holder.class);
        Log.d("-----", "pallavi");
        }
```

**holder class;**

```
public class Holder {
    List<deparaturedaseboarddto> data;
}
```

could I send response string than I use gson library ?

Comment: you are doing the bulk of the network call on the Main Thread (parsing the input stream), this should be done in doInBackground

Comment: Don't do network ops in the post execute but only in the background portion of the async task

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: can I use gson using response string ?

Comment: can I use gson using response string ? mean if I will send response as callback may I use gson library